# Representing knowledge extracted from output of dependency parsing

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees, parsing, python, summarization

I am working on a problem to represent knowledge extracted from a paragraph and rank it to produce abstractive summaries. I have implemented dependency parsing using Stanford NLP, which gives `dot` format graph as an output.

The dependency-parsed output of the following two sentences are as follows.

Sentence 1 - John is a computer scientist

Dot format -

```
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 5 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (John)"]
2 [label="2 (is)"]
3 [label="3 (a)"]
4 [label="4 (computer)"]
5 [label="5 (scientist)"]
5 -> 2 [label="cop"]
5 -> 4 [label="compound"]
5 -> 3 [label="det"]
5 -> 1 [label="nsubj"]
}
```

Graph -
 [image]

Sentence 2 - John has an elder sister named Mary.

Dot Format -

```
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 2 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (John)"]
2 [label="2 (has)"]
2 -> 5 [label="dobj"]
2 -> 1 [label="nsubj"]
3 [label="3 (an)"]
4 [label="4 (elder)"]
5 [label="5 (sister)"]
5 -> 6 [label="acl"]
5 -> 3 [label="det"]
5 -> 4 [label="amod"]
6 [label="6 (named)"]
6 -> 7 [label="dobj"]
7 [label="7 (Mary)"]
}
```

Graph -
 [image]

Now I want to merge this graph at a common node, `John`. I am currently using graphviz to import `dot` graph like this,

```
from graphviz import Source
s = Source(dotGraph, filename=filepath, format="png")
```

But there seems to be no functionality to merge graphs in `Graphviz`, or `Networkx`. So how can this be done?

Comment: Commissioner Gordon, turn on the `Merge` Signal. This is a case for the Biosyntax Squad.

Comment: What would your expected output look like? How exactly does that help you achieve your stated purpose?

Comment: The goal is to have all the information related to a particular entity, in the same graph. Further, it can be ranked and used to generate summaries.

Comment: I am a theoretical DG guy. I cannot comment on the computational side of what you are doing. I would, though, like to point out that the Stanford annotation scheme is controversial. For instance, your first dependency tree shows _scientist_ as the root of the sentence. From a linguistic point of view, a stronger case can be made for viewing the finite verb _is_ as the root.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using CoreNLP to generate dependency trees, a very nice way to tackle your problem would be to use the Tsurgeon library used to manipulate parse trees.

[Tsurgeon](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.html) is a (parse) tree transformation language. (Also check Tregex and SemGrex on the same link.)